# An electron's phase has to be shifted, forwards or backwards, by two full cycles to be indistinguishable from the original, correct?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, quantum-field-theory, electrons, education

Does anyone else watch PBS Space-Time with Matthew O'Dowd?

His most recent episode, 'Why Magnetic Monopoles SHOULD Exist', says, at 7:25 to 7:45, that the shift in an electron's quantum phase is unobserveable if it is shifted exactly ONE full cycle, not two...

Did I just find an error?  Or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: I'm not sure there's a physics question here: What is the definition of "full cycle"? Your "two cycles" sounds as if you're thinking of a *full $2\pi$ rotation*, which indeed does not return an electron to its original state, but perhaps the video you're citing is just using "cycle" to mean "shifting the phase until we arrive at the original state again".